# Titanium mobile - text into strings.xml shows variable name not content

Tags: xml, mobile, internationalization, titanium

I have a problem when using the command L('name_of_entry') into my titanium mobile application.

The preview into the simulator iOS works.

The entry `<string name="name_of_entry">Hello</string>` shows "hello".

But into the android emulator, the mobileweb preview AND on ipod touch iOS 5.1,this only shows name_of_entry.

Do you know what is the problem?

I show you the code that i used to call this.

first :

```
menuItemsTab[0] = new menuIconsItemModel(0, 'user_admin', pathImages + 'images/icon_user.png', L('user_admin_menu'),'UserAdminMainWindowController');
```

and after into the label:

```
text : item.text,
```

Please help ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found what the problem was... me!

The simulator looked into the strings.xml file into the en folder, but the language of my device is in french, and... the strings.xml file into the fr folder wasn't completed.

The switch between languages is automatic, i didn't know that!

Will try a way to change this setting and to memory this setting into a file or into sqlite db.